# Additional condition for equal values using MAX() function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a simple database for auctions. It includes a table that contains the bids.

```
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
| item_id | user_id | amount |    time    |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
|       3 |       2 |    500 | 1540152972 |
|       3 |       4 |    500 | 1540151466 |
+---------+---------+--------+------------+
```

At the end of the auction I need to find which users won which items (highest amount). I've considered the following query for that

```
SELECT item_id, user_id, MAX(amount)
FROM auction_bids
GROUP BY item_id
```

Which appears to work fine, until multiple users have made a bid with the same amount.

In that case I need to retrieve the earliest one (i.e: the lowest `time` value).

How do I work this into my `GROUP BY` query?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Your query is wrong anyway. You group by `item_id`, but select `user_id` without specifying which. So you just get one of the bidders per item arbitrarily chosen. (Other DBMS would raise an error, but MySQL converts `user_id` to `ANY_VALUE(user_id)` silently.) You may want to consider `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY'` to help you with such situations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a row if no other row with the same item_id has a higher price, or, if the prices are the same, the other row is later.

```
SELECT item_id, user_id, amount
FROM auction_bids a1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select 1 from auction_bids a2
                  where a2.item_id = a1.item_id
                    and (a2.amount > a1.amount
                         or (a2.amount = a1.amount and a2.time < a1.time)))
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is filtering, not aggregation:

```
SELECT ab.*
FROM auction_bids ab
WHERE ab.amount = (SELECT MAX(ab2.amount)
                   FROM auction_bids ab2
                   WHERE ab2.item_id = ab.item_id
                  );
```